# How to get a contents from Light weight rich text editor using j-query

Tags: javascript, jquery, rich-text-editor

I am using Light weight rich text editor to entering contents.After entered I was tried to get that entered contents using j-query,So that I ll use for other purposes.But it not getting.Please help me.

HTML form:

```
<form>
    <p>
        <textarea name="ta1" id="ta1" class="rte2"></textarea>
    </p>
<a id="various1" href="#inline1" style="text-decoration:blink"><input type="button" id="expand" name="expand" value="Expand"></a>
    <p></p>
    <div id="inline1" style="width:460px;height:320px;overflow:auto;">
    <p>
        <textarea name="ta2" id="ta2" class="rte1"></textarea>
    </p>    
    </div>
</form>
```

J-Query script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#expand").click(function () {
    var text = $("#ta1").text();
    alert(text); });

    //$("#various1").click(function(){
    //$("#inline1").hide(); 
    //});
```

Rich text editor toolbar j-query codes

```
    var arr = $('.rte1').rte({
        css: ['default.css'],
        width: 450,
        height: 200,
        controls_rte: rte_toolbar,
        controls_html: html_toolbar,
    });

    $('.rte2').rte({
        css: ['default.css'],
        width: 450,
        height: 200,
        controls_rte: rte_toolbar,
        controls_html: html_toolbar
    }, arr);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `$("#ta1").val();` textareas are input types, and the content of a text area is retrieved and set with `.value` and in jQuery case `.val()`

Comment: and please tell me how to copy a one textarea value to another textarea...In above code from textarea ta1 to textarea ta2.

Comment: $("#ta2").val($("#ta1").val())

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 var text = $("#ta1").text();
```

see i have used `.val()` instead of `.text()`

**DEMO Here**

http://jsfiddle.net/9YD5Q/